# btrfs on openSUSE not releasing disk space

Tags: filesystems, opensuse, disk-usage, btrfs

I have an openSUSE 12.1 install on my main desktop running with btrfs filesystem for root (/boot is ext4). I started having issues today with KDE informing me that disk space is almost all gone and eventually it decided it was gone and crashed my desktop.

I used Alt+F1 to switch to a terminal screen and although I was sure I was no where near the 1TB limit of my hard disk I moved some 150/200GB of music and video files onto an external drive and rebooted. Didn't help, same problem, same crash.

Once more I switched to a terminal screen and used du to confirm that I had indeed only used about half of my total diskspace but df (including the btrfs-progs version) insists I have used 100% of available diskspace and so my desktop crashes each and every time I log in.

Using the btrfs defrag utility doesn't help either. As such I am at a bit of a loss as to where to go next.

Comment: Please post the complete output of `df -PT`.

Comment: It's not feasible to type it all out given the situation but it too says that / is 100% full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually my system would no longer boot even to single user mode after attempting to fix so have re-installed.

Comment: Probably the not the best possible solution.

Answer (score 5):

openSUSE 12.1, if installed on btrfs, automatically enables tool called [snapper](http://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Snapper) which uses btrfs snapshotting to get snapshots of the system before installing new packages. It is well possible that these snapshots are consuming your disk space. Check out your snapshots with `snapper list` command.

Snapshots can be configured using `/etc/snapper/configs/root` (see `man 5 snapper-configs` for details).

You can list existing snapshots using `snapper -c root list`, and you can force removing older snapshots by:

- `snapper -c root cleanup timeline`
- `snapper -c root cleanup number`

See `man 8 snapper` for details.
Check out this [blogpost](http://www.nrtm.de/index.php/2012/03/13/the-joys-of-btrfs-and-opensuse-or-no-space-left-on-device/) for more information about btrfs/snapper/opensuse 12.1.

Comment: Actually the blog post is at http://www.nrtm.org/index.php/2012/03/13/the-joys-of-btrfs-and-opensuse-or-no-space-left-on-device/comment-page-1/
Many more people bump into this because `df` lies when `btrfs` is used. Too bad. I've written a blog post on this as well: http://wiert.me/2014/04/09/how-can-a-partition-be-full-if-du-does-not-show-it-is-via-linux-super-user-opensuse-btrfs-snapshots/